# Automatically get SQLite data and insert it into a class

Tags: c#, oop, sqlite, mvvm

I am still learning the MVVM pattern and am making a new project(C#4.0 & WPF) which involves SQLite databases. I haven't used databases(`sql`) much in the past, but what I would do is something like this:

```
Select * from persons;
```

then loop through the result and `foreach` result add it in the persons class, something like

```
result[0] = person.name; 
result[1] = person.id;
```

et cetera. Then I would use a `for` loop until I went through all the rows and added all the players to a `List` (or ObservableCollection for MVVM). Now I want to be more dynamic, since I'll have many more rows I am looking for something like:

```
Person personone = "Select * from persons where ID = 1";
```

But this doesn't work, of course. I have been tried searching for my question on Google but have not found an answer. I found SQL to LINQ but it is not really the thing I am looking for. The most relevant thing I found is the [massive sqlite class](https://github.com/robconery/massive/blob/master/Massive.Sqlite.cs), but it doesn't seem to work with VS11 as it appears to have been deprecated.

How can I more dynamically insert data from SQLite into a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) is a nice solution for this. You can map the results of your query to custom POCOs, or to dynamic objects.

Mapping the query results to an object is as simple as:

```
var cn = ... //create your db connection
IEnumerable<MyClass> myList = cn.Query<MyClass>("select * from MyTable").ToList();
```

For a single instance, you would do this:

```
MyClass myInstance = cn.Query<MyClass>("select * from MyTable where id = 1").SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, after looking into it I encounter a problem that I use a SQLiteConnection instead of a IDbConnection? My connection is made this way:  var con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:/hugetestfile.sqlite;Version=3;");. How can I create a SQlite connection with IDbConnection interface?

Comment: SQLiteConnection inherits from DbConnection so it should work fine as is.

Comment: You are right, Thanks alot! Btw I am not able to do cn.query I have to var testlist = Dapper.SqlMapper.Query<persons>(con, "select * from persons"); instead of var testlist = con.Query<Person>("select * from champions"); Quick solution why I fail here ?

Comment: Not sure - did you install Dapper using NuGet?

Comment: Nuget? no I just "imported" the class/code. I got it fixed stupid me. I had to add Using Dapper; ... sorry ^^ :D Thx again